# Order of $b$ when $ba=ab^3$ and $\operatorname{ord}(a)=4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a non-abelian group and let $a,b \in G$ such that
>
> 1. $\operatorname{ord}(a) = 4$, and
> 2. $ba=ab^3$
>
> Given that $\operatorname{ord}(b)$ is an odd prime number, compute its value.

So, $\operatorname{ord}(b)$ may be $3,5,7,11,13,...$ but I have no idea how I can compute it precisely.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 8):

You can find out a multiple of the order of $b$ by shifting $a^4 = e$ past $b$, one $a$ after the other:

$$\begin{align}
b &= b\cdot e = b(a^4) = (ba)(a^3) = a(b^3a)a^2\\
&= a (b^2ab^3)a^2 = a(bab^6)a^2 = a^2 (b^9) a^2\\
&= a^3(b^{27}a) = a^4 b^{81}\\
&= b^{81}
\end{align}$$

So we have $b^{81} = b \iff b^{80} = e$, hence the order of $b$ divides $80 = 2^4\cdot 5$. The order of $b$ is an odd prime dividing $80$, hence $5$.

Comment: Ok, but i have a lot of problem with fallow yours resolution. If i see similar task I'm always confused, because I don't know what I should make in first and next steps. Is it any algorithm how can I solve similar tasks? Could you give me any advice?

Comment: No algorithm, but when you don't know how to proceed, multiplying with $1$ or adding $0$ (not literally, but here you know that $a^4 = e$, so try that), and just playing around, moving parts from one side to the other, often helps. It's a matter of practice to see what looks promising, just fiddle around with some exercises you find in books.

Answer (score 3):

Also, there is a bit similar way to @Daniel attempt. We have $ba=ab^3$ so we have $$a^{-1}ba=b^3\to b=ab^3a^{-1}=(aba^{-1})^3$$ so:
 $$b=(aba^{-1})^3=\left(a(aba^{-1})^3a^{-1}\right)^3=(a^2b^3a^{-2})^3=(a^2ba^{-2})^{3^2}=...=(a^4ba^{-4})^{3^4}=b^{81}$$

Comment: $+^\infty\quad$ I can't seem to get "on a roll" at math.se. I've gotten a fair amount done, but not at math.se. Especially not for a Sunday.